# post in FB wall through an application, by an application user to his friend

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, fb.ui

I have created an application. When one user accepts this application I have successfully store his/her all friend list. Now I want to post to post my users friends wall if my user want. But the problem is when I am trying to post then then this error is shown:

```
API Error Code: 240
API Error Description: Desktop applications cannot call this function for other users
Error Message: User needs to be admin of the page
```

But it is not possible to make all user in my app to be an admin. So what should I do to post it ? If I need to use accesstoken, so how can I use it? Or is this is an error is shown as I am just a desktop user?

I am posting as:

```
function postonwall()
{ 
    FB.init({ appId:'app_id', cookie:true, status:true, xfbml:true }); 
    FB.ui({ method:'feed',from:'xxx' ,to:'yyy' , message: 'HI'}, function(response){ 
        if (response && response.post_id) 
        { 
           alert('Post was published.'); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            alert('Post was not published.'); 
        } 
     }); 
 }
function warmup()
{ 
    FB.init({ appId:'app_id', cookie:true, status:true, xfbml:true }); 
} 
</script> 
<a href="thispage.php" onclick="postonwall();"><div class="quote"><h2>post message</a>
```

Comment: Show us some more code.

Comment: In which part you want to see? where may the problem you think? Then I will show you that. Entire code is too big

Comment: How may I know what all functions have you used? Post the code after which the fb throws this error

Comment: function postonwall(){
         FB.init({
            appId:'app_id', cookie:true,
            status:true, xfbml:true
         });
         FB.ui({ method:'feed',from:'xxx' ,to:'yyy' ,
            message: 'HI'},

function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
 alert('Post was published.');
     
    } else {
       alert('Post was not published.');
    }
  }
);
}
   
function warmup(){
FB.init({
       appId:'app_id', cookie:true,
       status:true, xfbml:true
     });
}
</script>
 <a href="thispage.php" onclick="postonwall();"><div class="quote"><h2>post message</a>

Comment: please see this and give me some solution, solution will be cordially accepted.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code there itself

Comment: Where did you saw this error? I cant see in your post code that you've priinted the error message

Comment: when I click "post message" then this is shown. This is an API error that is predefined by fb developers.

Comment: Yes I know that. Did you saw any popup or not? THe `from` is your app user and the `to` is the Page ID right?

Comment: I also try accessToken in fb.ui. but the result is same error.

Comment: THe from is your app user and the to is the Page ID right?

Comment: no. from is my app user and to is a friend of my app user.

Comment: Try this direct url: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?%20%20app_id=<app-id>%20%20&display=popup&caption=An%20example%20caption%20%20%20&link=http://google.com&redirect_uri=<redirect-url>&to=<friend-id>

Comment: it is also not working, and this means that I am postion a message to my users friend. I want that my user will give me a permission to post on his friends wall.

Comment: What error are you getting from the direct link?

Comment: no error is shown. It happens nothing.

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong for sure, pls replace the app-id, redirect url carefully